# Trigger recalculation of certain UDF

Tags: vba, excel

Imagine that I have an UDF `MyFunc` and users can call this function in Excel like`=MyFunc(A1)`

Under the hood, MyFunc references to a certain range of cells. To simplify things, let's say MyFunc is equivalent to `Vlookup(A1, B1:E10, 4, FALSE)`, so `B1:E10` is hard coded

I understand that when the calculation mode is set to `automatic`, the result would update when `A1` updates. The question is:

**How can I design this function so that it updates when either `A1` or `B1:E10` changes?**

Can I explicitly add some sort of reference to where this function looks in VBA?

Please advice

**EDIT 1**

`Public Function MyFunc(val As Variant) As Variant
    MyFunc = Application.VLookup(val, Range("B1:E10"), 2, False)
End Function`

I was hoping that something like the following would work, but apparently it doesn't

`Public Function MyFunc(val As Variant, Optional rng As Range = Range("B1:E10")) As Variant
    MyFunc = Application.VLookup(val, rng, 2, False)
End Function`

**EDIT 2**

One way I can think of is to keep track of where `MyFunc` gets called in the excel spreadsheet, and fire off the recalc of these cells when the referenced range `B1:E10` changes. But I'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Why not include those references in the arguments to your UDF?  Then you don't need some other mechanism to manage updates.

Comment: thank you @TimWilliams I tried to add the range reference as the second argument in my UDF and set some default value. But it seems that the default value has to be constant, and the range object is dynamic? Please shed some light

Comment: vba code `range("a1")=range("a1")`, that would be called whenever B1:E10 changed would recalculate the UDF. ... but the UDF would only work in  A1, unless some type of a UDF registration mechanism was involved

Comment: you mentioned that you do not want to use a volatile UDF (this was in response to an answer that i have since retracted) .... if that is because the UDF is complex, and a multiple of UDFs would slow down the worksheet, then maybe you could still make the UDF volatile, but put in a check for which cells have changed (not sure if that is possible .... just an idea)

Comment: i got it ...  sort of .... cumbersome though ... put all the UDFs on a separate worksheet and recalculate that sheet when needed ... not very user friendly

Comment: how many of the UDFs are you expecting to have on a worksheet?

Comment: It would help to show the code for your UDF.  I not sure how to "shed some light", since it's not clear at all what your UDF actually does.

Comment: @TimWilliams added

Comment: @jsotola The sheet/workbook might have a lot of other functions that don't want to be recalculated. So that doesn't sound promising, unless there's a way to only invoke the recalc of `MyFunc` for the entire workbook, regardless of where it gets called.

Comment: It would work as `Public Function MyFunc(val As Variant, rng As Range) As Variant` (ie. you would need to supply the range, since that's how Excel tracks calculation dependencies.  BTW your function has a significant problem with the use of `Range("B1:E10")` - without a worksheet qualifier, that reference will refer to the *active sheet* (which might be different from the sheet you intend to reference).  This would mean your UDF might return different values depending on which sheet is active...   Assuming your UDF is in a regular module, not the sheet code module.

Comment: this may work ... works for me ... when `Range("B1:E10")` changes, search the worksheet for every occurrence of the UDF call ( look for formula `=MyFunc(xxx)` ) and when found do `Range(where UDF found).formula = "=MyFunc(xxx)"`

Comment: of course, you will need a worksheet_update macro

Comment: loop all formula cells .... `For Each formulaCell In Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you. I guess there's no way for me to supply the `rng` with some non-const default value. guess that's not achievable in any language...

Comment: @jsotola Thank you. I get what you mean... I imagine it would work, but looping through all possible cells doesn't sound like an ideal solution. Guess the root cause of this problem is that I want the function to reference some range, but the range could change in run time. so the compiler must not allow this behavior....

Answer (score 1):

Create a routine that's triggered by the worksheet change event of the worksheet that holds your data (B1:B10). Check if the range that's changed is within your range, and if so, loop through all formulas in all sheets to find your udf and use range.calculate on them

Comment: We talked about this in the comments above -- it's doable, but doesn't sound like an ideal solution. I'd imagine it gets slower and slower as the number of sheets grows up, no?

Comment: marginally, but you only run the actual routine if your B1:B10 actually changes so if you have your lookup on a separate sheet that rarely changes there's no cost at all.